# htaccess - append language variable to all url based on folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with multiple languages and languages are managed through folders.

So www.domain.com/es/ - www.domain.com/de/ - and so on.
What I wish to do, through the htaccess, is to take the language and use it as a variable for any filename of the website.
As an example
www.domain.com/es/  -->  www.domain.com?language=es
www.domain.com/es/myfile.php  -->  www.domain.com/myfile.php?language=es

is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)language=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?language=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: it works!! :)     Is there a way to hide the variable (language=$1)? Thank you